# Unable to delete wrong package name app bundle or upload correct app bundle

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

1. What were you doing when you ran into the problem?
   Answer: upload the app bundle
2. At which step did the problem occur?
   Answer: when uploading app bundle
3. What were you expecting to happen?
   Answer: to be able to upload
4. What actually happened?
   Answer: package name is incorrect
5. What is the model and OS version of the device you were using?
   Answer:  Window 10
6. Which version is the SDK of your kit? If the AR Engine is used, provide the AR Engine version number.
   Answer:
7. Paste a screenshot of what you saw when the problem occurred.
   Answer:

Comment: Please add more details info for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change the app package, ensure that the version code of the uploaded app package is later than that of the released version. Otherwise, the package upload will fail.

For details , please refer to [link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-help-update-version-0000001146436549):